# How to use boost async_read with return message has no terminated character and size?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to implement a ssl-client with async socket which send and receive protobuf messages from a server. The format of the message is the first 4 bytes is indicated the size of the message follows (X), the rest is the respond message which has X bytes.

The problem is I don't know how to take the first 4 bytes to get the message size to read the rest.

`async_read()`  need the exact size, which is 4 bytes but I don't know what to do next?
`async_read_until()` required a terminated character which the message doesn't have.

How to do this? I came from Java and C# and not really familiar with boost and C++.

The source code is attached below. Pls search "TODO" to reach the LOC that do the read things...

PS: I can't change anything from the server. Only have the binaries :(

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include "client/connection/authentication.pb.h"
#include "client/connection/authentication.pb.cc"
#include "client/msg.pb.h"
#include "client/msg.pb.cc"
#include "client/common.pb.h"
#include "client/common.pb.cc"

class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
  : socket_(io_service, context)
  {
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;

    return preverified;
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if(!error){
      std::cout << "Connection OK!" << std::endl;
      socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client, boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }else{
      std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if(!error){
      std::cout << "Sending request: " << std::endl;

//      std::stringstream request_;

//      request_ << "GET /api/0/data/ticker.php HTTP 1.1\r\n";
//      request_ << "Host: mtgox.com\r\n";
//      request_ << "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
//      request_ << "\r\n";

      protobuf::Message msg;

      char *data = new char[dlen];
      bool ok = msg.SerializeToArray(data,dlen);

  //    uint32_t n = htonl(dlen);
      uint32_t n = dlen;
  //    char bytes[4];
  //    bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
  //    bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
  //    bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
  //    bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;

      int sizeOfPacket = 4 + dlen;
      char* rq = new char[sizeOfPacket];
  //    strncpy(rq, bytes, 4);

      rq[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
      rq[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
      rq[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
      rq[3] = n & 0xFF;

      strncpy(rq + 4,data, dlen);

//       request_<< rq;
//      std::cerr << request_.str() << std::endl;

      boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(rq,sizeOfPacket), boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }else{
      std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error){
      std::cout << "Sending request OK!" << std::endl;
      char respond[4] = "";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(respond,4),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read,
          this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
//      std::cerr << "respond is " << respond;
//TODO

    }else{
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error){
      std::cout << "Reply: ";
      std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
      std::cout << "\n";
    }else{
      std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
  char reply_[0x1 << 16];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.2.32", "443");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::ssl::context context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
//    context.load_verify_file("key.pem");

    client c(io_service, context, iterator);

    io_service.run();
  }catch (std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Update: Are there anything wrong in this implement?

```
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error){
      std::cout << "Sending request OK!" << std::endl;
      char respond[4] = "";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(respond,4),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read,
          this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

      int sizeOfMessage = getSizeFromHeader(respond);//need implement
      char message[sizeOfMessage] ="";
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message,sizeOfMessage),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read,
          this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
      decodeMessage(message);
//      std::cerr << "respond is " << respond;
//TODO


    }else{
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: *but I don't know what to do next?* If you know the size of the following message, why not call the exact same function (`async_read`) with that knowledge?

Comment: Hi; I don't really know the behaviour of `boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(respond,4),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_read,
          this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));` when call it again, is there some kind of marker that mark the read begin at the 5th element?

Comment: No, but if you read something in my understanding it will be deleted from the buffer (like pop from stack). If you read directly after getting the first 4 bites, you should get the complete message.

Comment: Hi I wrote some code based on your idea (at the end of the question)? Do you find anything wrong, pls help me review.

Comment: when calling a function with char[] as parameter always give a second parameter `int size` or just use string which has a `size()` method. Aside from this it should work, but I cannot test it this is up to you :)

Comment: I will feedback later. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
  char message[sizeOfMessage] ="";
  boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message,sizeOfMessage),
    boost::bind(&client::handle_read,
      this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  decodeMessage(message);
```

This can't ever work, since `message` is a local variable so it ceases to exist before the async operation runs/completes.

Same here:

```
        char respond[4] = "";
        ba::async_read(
            socket_, ba::buffer(respond, 4),
            boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this, ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        //      std::cerr << "respond is " << respond;
        // TODO
```

Funny thing in `handle_read` you don't use that, you use `reply_` which is a member. That's a lot better.

---

```
        char *data = new char[dlen];
        bool ok = msg.SerializeToArray(data, dlen);
```

`dlen` is not defined. Even if you do define it, `ok` is never checked. Ouch. Next, `data` is never `deleted[]`-ed.

```
        uint32_t n = dlen;
        //    char bytes[4];
        //    bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
        //    bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
        //    bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
        //    bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;

        int sizeOfPacket = 4 + dlen;
        char *rq = new char[sizeOfPacket];
        //    strncpy(rq, bytes, 4);

        rq[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
        rq[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
        rq[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
        rq[3] = n & 0xFF;

        strncpy(rq + 4, data, dlen);
```

By now you copied it all (even if serialization failed) another time, and have another memory leak, this time 4 bytes larger.

```
        //      std::cerr << request_.str() << std::endl;
```

Writing binary data to `std::cerr` is not going to be pretty (and will usually just not work because of 0-chars).

---

Now finally when you `handle_read` you're likely to encounter SSL `SSL_R_SHORT_READ` because of the fact that your buffer has a fixed size and response might be smaller (if the response is larger, you won't know). So handle that case:

```
    if (!error || error == ssl::error::stream_errors::stream_truncated) {
```

### Somewhat Fixed Sample

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e2c91d563132b4d)</kbd>**

```
//#include "client/common.pb.cc"
//#include "client/common.pb.h"
//#include "client/connection/authentication.pb.cc"
//#include "client/connection/authentication.pb.h"
//#include "client/msg.pb.cc"
//#include "client/msg.pb.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/error.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
namespace ssl = ba::ssl;
using ba::ip::tcp;

static constexpr int dlen = 300;

namespace protobuf {
    struct Message {
        bool SerializeToArray(char* p, size_t n) {
            strncpy(p, "hello world\n", n);
            return true;
        }
    };
} // namespace protobuf

class client {
  public:
    client(ba::io_service &io_service, ssl::context &context, tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
            : socket_(io_service, context) 
    {
        socket_.set_verify_mode(ssl::context::verify_none);
        socket_.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

        ba::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
                          boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this, ba::placeholders::error));
    }

    bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context &ctx) {
        char subject_name[256];
        X509 *cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
        std::cout << "Verifying:\n" << subject_name << std::endl;

        return preverified;
    }

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Connection OK!" << std::endl;
            socket_.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client,
                                    boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this, ba::placeholders::error));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Sending request: " << std::endl;

            // prepare request_ buffer
            {
                request_.consume(request_.size());
                std::ostream os(&request_);
                os << "GET /api/0/data/ticker.php HTTP 1.1\r\n";
                os << "Host: mtgox.com\r\n";
                os << "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
                os << "\r\n";

                std::vector<char> data(dlen + 4); // perhaps avoid SerializeToArray and skip the copy

                // fill length
                {
                    uint32_t n = htonl(dlen);
                    data[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
                    data[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
                    data[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
                    data[3] = n & 0xFF;
                }

                // fill message
                {
                    protobuf::Message msg;
                    bool ok = msg.SerializeToArray(data.data() + 4, dlen);

                    if (!ok)
                        throw std::runtime_error("Do something!");
                }

                // write buffer
                os.write(data.data(), data.size());
            }

            ba::async_write(
                socket_, request_,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Sending request OK! (" << bytes_transferred << " bytes)" << std::endl;
            ba::async_read(
                socket_, ba::buffer(reply_),
                boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this, ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        } else {
            std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!error || error == ssl::error::stream_errors::stream_truncated) {
            std::cout << "Reply: ";
            std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
            std::cout << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

  private:
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
    ba::streambuf request_;
    char reply_[1 << 16];
};

int main() {
    try {
        ba::io_service io_service;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.2.32", "443");
        tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        ssl::context context(ssl::context::sslv23);
        // context.load_verify_file("key.pem");

        client c(io_service, context, iterator);

        io_service.run();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

When tested against a local test SSL server (passphrase "test"):

```
openssl s_server -accept 6767 -cert ~/custom/boost/libs/asio/example/cpp03/ssl/server.pem -CAfile ~/custom/boost/libs/asio/example/cpp03/ssl/ca.pem
```

It printed:

```
./sotest 
Connection OK!
Verifying:
/C=AU/ST=NSW/L=Sydney/O=asio
Sending request: 
Sending request OK! (380 bytes)
error: asio.ssl:335544539 (short read)
Reply: asdasdasdasdasd
```

Obviously, `asdasdasdasdasd` is the response I typed in the `s_server` end.

Comment: Thank for the code sample and pointing out my mistakes. The code is striped the field in the protobuf message due to the private things, I accidently remove some necessary line. Can you help me sample version of `void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)` it would receive the message has the first 4 bytes is indicated the size of the message follows (X), the rest is the respond message (protobuf) which has X bytes.